# Java Argument skips $ symbol

Tags: java

I have this program to encrypt and decrypt the password,
However I'm facing below issue, when the run the program from console. But, its running fine from eclipse.

How can I avoid this issue?

### The entered value has $ symbol in it, but that is skipped in program.

```
java -jar IGL_DP_PassEnc.jar W@7erTp98$b

Entered Password : W@7erTp98

Encrypted Value: 0rJPtIeYICfdJyxWT2RmYg==

Decrypted Value: W@7erTp98
```

Comment: Can you please share some of your code?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ptZ9wuAR

Comment: Edit your question to contain your code, don't link it. Well formatted and researched questions are more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your parameter in single quotes; $b is interpreted as a variable name.

Comment: Perfect.. It works.. thanks.
I was so into it... Tried with double quotes (") many times.
Never checked with single quote.